# Using NOT operator with Squeel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, squeel

How do I write a SQL query using Squeel?

```
    SELECT * FROM documents where (NOT document.deleted OR document.deleted IS NULL)
```

I tried:

```
    Document.where { (-deleted) | (deleted == nil) }
```

but get this error:

```
    NoMethodError: undefined method `|' for deleted.-@:Squeel::Nodes::KeyPath
```

Comment: what you mean by `NOT document.deleted`?

Comment: Thats mean deleted not equal true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very important to notice that ActiveRecord stores boolean values as string flags in the database. Therefore, in the case you mentioned, `document.deleted` equals `'f'` which is a *truthy value*. That's why you can't simply use the `NOT` operator.

Perhaps what you're looking for is:

```
Document.where { deleted.eq(false) | deleted.eq(nil) }
```

Cheers

Comment: Just a quick advice: in your migrations, make your boolean columns default to `false`. Then you can avoid all the annoying `| foo.eq(nil)` clauses.

Answer (score 2):

`NOT` will reverse the returned set, so you must define what you are comparing.

```
(-deleted) #there is nothing to reverse
```

Based in your comment, I think you mean `deleted not equal true`, so:

```
Document.where { -(deleted == true) | (deleted == nil) }
```

However, reverse of true is false, right? So, you can say:

```
Document.where { (deleted == false) | (deleted == nil) }
```